# How can I get basic auth information from browser

Tags: javascript, security, browser, basic-authentication

My backend needs basic auth Authorization header.

```
'Authorization': 'Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ'
```

The problem I have is, that I need to use the **native basic auth prompt** from the browser and I don't know how to get the basic auth info in my javascript frontend application. In other words: I need to get the username and password from the browsers basic auth propmt.

**Can anyone tell me how to get the basic auth info from the browsers native basic auth prompt?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign basic authentication header to XMLHTTPREQUEST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332747/where-to-store-auth-token-frontend-and-how-to-put-it-in-http-headers-of-multip

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/3460337/214446

Answer (score 0):

To get a token request from backend( like login request) in response you will get token thne use can save in s

```
// Store
sessionStorage.setItem("Authorization", "dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ");
// Retrieve
let token = sessionStorage.getItem("Authorization");
```

For API call use fetch

For add Authorization header code

```
   let token = sessionStorage.getItem("Authorization");
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " +token;

    fetch("https://url", {
        headers: headers
      })
      .then((response) => { ... })
      .done();
```

Comment: I know how to add it to the request. I don't know how to get it from the browser...

Comment: @LorenzPfisterer I have updated my answer. if any confusion or help please let me know

Comment: The problem is that the value of the Authorization header is not static. It is provided by the user using the browsers native basic auth prompt. I don't know how to get that info.

Comment: @LorenzPfisterer like this http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/08/25/using-the-browsers-native-login-prompt/

Comment: @LorenzPfisterer you can try http://www.javaxt.com/wiki/Tutorials/Javascript/Form_Based_HTTP_Authentication