# Digest authentication: Get browser stored username from javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, digest-authentication

I have a web server serving static pages with a digest authentication. I would like to show logged user's name on a page with javascript without making requests to the server (since browsers store credentials in case of basic/digest authentication).

Quick search showed no solution so i wonder if its possible to get the stored username with javascript.

**Upd:** This question duplicates the old one [Get the HTTP Basic Auth username from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460299/get-the-http-basic-auth-username-from-javascript) Just wish to know if something changed in that matter

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried LocalStorage?

For to set a item you could use:

```
localStorage.setItem('itemName', 'itemData');

localStorage.getItem('itemName');
```

You can, as well, use:

for delete item

```
localStorage.removeItem('itemName')
```

and delete all

```
localStorage.clear()
```

it will be placed on browser memory always as a string, you can check the data on your devtools on Application tab inside the local storage data. it will be reset with clear cache or the .clear() function.

So if it is sensitive data please make sure you encrypt or protect in some way.

Here the API documentation so you can search more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage